# What can I tell someone struggling with addiction?

Tags: desire

I have a family member who practices Buddhism and says there is nothing of use there for addiction. She doesnt have a runaway out of control issue but it is a problem. I think she drinks every night. She works and meditates though. What do the Hindu scriptures say that might have some wisdom that would help? I have never seen anything addressing it. It seems to be more than just normal craving and human desire etc, and not just more but a different animal.

Note: Only looking for scriptures or practices that are specific to addiction or substance use or alcohol use, not comparisons of those problems with desire in general

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: A person’s company can influence his choices and his charecter.The person afflicted should do as much japa,kirtan as possible,initially in the company of other devotees.There is the *bliss* that a bhakt experiences ,when he is wholeheartedly lost in the remembrance of his ishta.The mind always looks for higher pleasure.(Worldly pleasure is characterised by dopamine release in the brain.To achieve the same high that the earlier experience gave,the addicted has to use higher/more stronger doses of the substance.Devotional pleasure only progresses higher and higher,with japa/kirtan).(1/n)

Comment: The sufferer’s mind will let go of the addiction,when this devotional pleasure surpasses the dopamine drive)After this,she  will know as to what she should do with regards to her Bhakti,and how to balance it with her worldly life.Scriptures say that in the Kali Yuga,japa and kirtan are the fastest way to attain moksha.What I have said is just ** my opinion **,I don’t know if scriptures speak of de addictive remedies,or whether what I suggested is actually necessary for her.The decision is to be taken by the stakeholder.So approach this issue with caution.(2/2)

Comment: Thank you that really is good

Comment: My pleasure,hope she can weed out the addiction early on.

Comment: Youre welcome to make that an answer if you like